# Save checkbox in SQL db with buddypress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, checkbox, buddypress

I'm using buddypress on my wordpress site and want to store a checkbox value to the custom profile fields. Users need to be able to check the checkbox when registering for the site. I know how to add *a* value to the xprofile field, I just don't know what the format of the value should be.

When looking into phpMyAdmin I see the values for the checkbox are: 
'a:1:{i:0;s:2:"True";}' for true, and
'a:0:{}' for false.

What does this all mean? Are these wp / bp specific? Should I just write these exact values into the db for everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the checkbox via the DashBoard > Users > Profile Fields ? 
If you add it to the 'Base' group, it should show up on the register form. 
And BP will handle the saving for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but no, I want to be able to add a checkbox to my custom registration page.

Comment: Use function xprofile_set_field_data to save the data. It should save it in the correct format - which is serialized.

Comment: I do use that function, but want to know what value to store. Should I use 'a:1:{i:0;s:2:"True";}' or just 'True'? I don't know anything about SQL. Thanks!

Comment: Pass the value of the checkbox to that function. Have you tried it? If you insist on not looking at what the function does, then google 'serialized field mysql' and write your own function.

Comment: Took me a while to understand the function alters the value, didn't even think about that. Thanks!